# Convert varchar to date in Oracle SQL with month name

Tags: sql, oracle, date, varchar

I have 2 columns in a large data set. 
Col 1 "review_date" is a varchar "September 16, 2019" I would like to have this information in DATE format as 09/16/2019

Col 2 "complete_date" is a varchar "20190916" I would like to have this information in DATE format as 09/16/2019

I have to apply this to both columns for the entire table. I am at a lost for col 1, because of the month being spelled out, and col 2 is not working for me using to_date(). My goal is to have this information even if new columns have to be created

Comment: Are you familiar with the `to_date()` function?  If so, do you still have a question?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "MMDDYYYY DATE variable".  There are dates which have an internal binary representation that is not human readable and there are strings which have a format.  Is the goal to return a string in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format?  Or to return a date?  Also, are you trying to write a single expression for both input strings or separate expressions for the different input string formats?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: What did you try? Using `TO_DATE()` should work.

Comment: The answer provided works on both - Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
        TO_DATE(review_date, 'MONTH DD, 
        YYYY' )

       TO_DATE(complete_date, 
       'YYYYMMDD')
```

This will read your data in the given month dd yyyy format and will convert to orackes default date format. You cannot actually modify the default date format using to_date() but can use to_char() to store modified date format as varchar

Comment: Thank you @Himanshu. This answer works for both when "complete_date" format is YYYYMMDD

Comment: You should include the language, e.g. `TO_DATE(review_date, 'MONTH DD, 
        YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH' )`

Comment: Umm yeah thanks..i missed as per Op's query and NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE by default i guess it would be english